# Elasticsearch multiget vs parent-child vs nested documents?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

I am moving a large amount of data from MySQL to ElasticSearch. I have a few relationships that are more like parent child (actor/activity). Actor produces a lot of activities. Currently I am storing actor ID inside each activity and storing actor data as a separate type. Whenever I want a large list of actor information (related to thousands of activities), I am doing a multi-get on the actor type. Is this the optimal way of doing things? I have read about parent/child relation ships and nested documents, but chose this way(multi-get) of doing thing as it seemed less complex.

Comment: It might be easy to answer, if you post your mapping and multiget query somewhere.